# georectification via SLD is not appearing at the correct place

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, sld, orthorectification

I am trying to georectify layers on the fly (feeded by Geoserver) in OpenLayers.

To do so, we have created a style (SLD) in Geoserver that does the georectification provided that we feed it a projection and coordinates via the GET request (`env` variable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
      <Name>GeorectifyCoverage</Name>
      <UserStyle>
        <Title>Georectify Coverage</Title>
        <Abstract>Warps image to specified GCP</Abstract>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
          <Transformation>
            <ogc:Function name="gs:GeorectifyCoverage">
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>gcp</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>wms_gcp</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>targetCRS</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>wms_crs</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>                
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>transparent</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>wms_transparent</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>                
              </ogc:Function>   
            </ogc:Function>
          </Transformation>

          <Rule>
           <RasterSymbolizer>
             <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
           </RasterSymbolizer>
         </Rule>

        </FeatureTypeStyle>
      </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I then display the layer over an OSM map with and pass the coordinates of the georectification through the `env` argument:

```
var wms5 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Geotiff5", "http://mydomain.com/foobar",
                    {
                        layers: data[0].imagename+":"+data[0].imagename,
                        styles: "georectify2",
                        env: "wms_transparent:false;wms_crs:EPSG:900913;wms_gcp:"+getGCP(pixel,coord3),
                        transparent: true
                    },
                    {
                        singleTile: true, 
                        isBaseLayer: false,
                        displayOutsideMaxExtent: true
                    }
                );
```

where

```
getGCP(pixel,coord3)="[[[0, 0], [725801.41007875, 5861382.4105691]], [[0, 450], [725725.04490808, 5858019.2685367]], [[600, 0], [725801.41007875, 5861382.4105691]], [[600, 450], [733521.52808368, 5859280.356713]]]"
```

I get a result where the layer is rectified, but the it doesn't appear at the right place, and the image is not cropped. I did a screenshot of the result. The polyon represents where the image should be, and the picture is just a [random image](http://topo.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/topo/files/images/ULM2.jpg) I used for testing purposes. One can see that the upper left and lower right corner are missing.

I don't know if using a SLD is the most elegant solution, but it is the only one I found to do it on the fly.

Any Ideas?

[image: The result of the georectification via SLD]